# Yocto fails to boot after adding package

Tags: linux, xilinx, yocto, recipe, bitbake

I'm about to build a Linux-Yocto filesystem for Xilinx Zynq platform.
Everything runs fine until I added one more package to the rootfs.
It doesn't matter what kind of package I'm adding it always fails with:

```
INIT: version 2.88 booting

/etc/init.d/rcS: line 17: mount: command not found
/etc/init.d/rc: line 66: stty: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S02banner.sh: line 11: /bin/mknod: No such file or directory
/etc/rcS.d/S02sysfs.sh: line 14: mount: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S02sysfs.sh: line 17: grep: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S06checkroot.sh: line 142: mount: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S06checkroot.sh: line 145: ln: command not found
Starting Bootlog daemon: bootlogd: cannot find console device 249:0 under /dev
bootlogd.
/etc/rcS.d/S37populate-volatile.sh: line 12: dirname: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S37populate-volatile.sh: line 13: sed: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S37populate-volatile.sh: line 193: /proc/cmdline: No such file or directory
/etc/rcS.d/S38devpts.sh: line 13: grep: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S38dmesg.sh: line 17: dmesg: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S39hostname.sh: line 10: /bin/hostname: No such file or directory
/etc/rcS.d/S39hostname.sh: line 19: hostname: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S55bootmisc.sh: line 64: date: command not found
/etc/rcS.d/S55bootmisc.sh: l
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5

/etc/init.d/rc: line 66: stty: command not found
Starting ntpd: /etc/rc5.d/S20ntpd: line 42: start-stop-daemon: command not found
done
Stopping Bootlog daemon: /etc/rc5.d/S99stop-bootlogd: line 62: start-stop-daemon: command not found
bootlogd.
```

And:

```
INIT: cannot execute "/sbin/getty"cannot execute "/sbin/getty"
INIT: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: cannot execute "/sbin/getty"
INIT: Id "PS0" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
```

My local.conf:

```
MACHINE ?= "zedboard-zynq7"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K" 

PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qemu-native = "sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-nativesdk-qemu = "sdl"
ASSUME_PROVIDED += "libsdl-native"
CONF_VERSION = "1"

#AT-ubifs config
MKUBIFS_ARGS = "-m 2048 -e 126976 -c 1884"

#added by hob
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_rpm "

#added by hob
DL_DIR = "/home/jonas/Zynq_AT_Debug/Yocto/poky/build/downloads"

#added by hob
SSTATE_DIR = "/home/jonas/Zynq_AT_Debug/Yocto/poky/build/sstate-cache"

#added by hob
SSTATE_MIRRORS = ""

#added by hob
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 8"

#added by hob
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "8"

#added by hob
INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE = ""

#added by hob
SDKMACHINE = "x86_64"

#added by hob
http_proxy = ""

#added by hob
https_proxy = ""

#added by hob
ftp_proxy = ""

#added by hob
all_proxy = ""

#added by hob
CVS_PROXY_HOST = ""

#added by hob
CVS_PROXY_PORT = ""

#added by hob
IMAGE_EXTRA_SPACE = "0"

#added by hob
TOOLCHAIN_BUILD = "False"

#added by hob
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "ubifs cpio"

#added by hob
LINGUAS_INSTALL = ""
```

My Image recipe:

```
require /home/jonas/Zynq_AT_Debug/Yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL = "sysvinit-pidof \
update-alternatives-opkg shadow-securetty init-ifupdown \
initscripts-functions base-files update-rc.d \
run-postinsts openssh udev-cache zlib libcrypto \
util-linux-libblkid openssh-scp openssh-keygen \
mtd-utils-ubifs initscripts openssh-ssh \
udev-utils modutils-initscripts eglibc \
shadow netbase openssh-sshd udev base-passwd  \
sysvinit mtd-utils openssl-conf libkmod lzo \
util-linux-libuuid libwrap sysvinit-inittab \
iperf nbench-byte ntp ntpdate nano"
    DESCRIPTION = "***** Yocto-filesystem"
```

If I take out nano everything is fine. 
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

To add more package into the rootfs,
in conf/local.conf add this line:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nano"`

The space in front is really important.

In addition, please show where you get your bsp and your conf/bblayers.conf

Edit:

Let's start from the beginning. Copy this, replace my local.conf to yours local.conf.  With this minimal set up, you could at least `bitbake core-image-minimal`

Then, to add your packages into the image, just add them to  `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " "`

```
MACHINE ?= "zedboard-zynq7"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks ssh-server-openssh package-manager"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K" 

PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qemu-native = "sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-nativesdk-qemu = "sdl"
ASSUME_PROVIDED += "libsdl-native"
CONF_VERSION = "1"

#AT-ubifs config
MKUBIFS_ARGS = "-m 2048 -e 126976 -c 1884"
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_rpm "
DL_DIR = "/home/jonas/Zynq_AT_Debug/Yocto/poky/build/downloads"
SSTATE_DIR = "/home/jonas/Zynq_AT_Debug/Yocto/poky/build/sstate-cache"
SSTATE_MIRRORS = ""
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j ${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
SDKMACHINE = "x86_64"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "ubifs cpio"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nano smartpm openssh-sftp-server "
```

Comment: thanks @LightenS for answering :)
I tried to do it like you said but had no luck :(
Same Error like before. The config/bblayers.conf is made by oe-init-build-env as far as i know. I expanded it by two of my own layers and the xilinx meta layer. the BSP is generated by xsdk based on the vivado hardware design.

Comment: There are a lot of stuff you added in the Image I don't understand and could not find them in the openembedded meta index.  So why don't we start fresh from the beginning, by compiling a core-minimal image and add the stuff you know that are necessary.